# Dynamic menu with ASP.NET MVC 4 and jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I'm working on an ASP.NET MVC 4 module which should display multilevel menu in my view based on data taken from database. Since I have no clear idea how to complete the entire task I decided to do it step by step in a way I think I think I will end up with the final result I want.

I've done some googling and now I have this :

class `MenuItem` :

```
public class MenuItem
{
  public MenuItem()
  {
    this.ChildMenuItems = new List<MenuItem>();
  }

  public int MenuItemId { get; set; }
  public string MenuItemName { get; set; }
  public string MenuItemPath { get; set; }
  public Nullable<int> ParentItemId { get; set; }
  public virtual ICollection<MenuItem> ChildMenuItems { get; set; }
}
```

and class `Menu` :

```
public class Menu
{
  public Menu()
  {
    Items = new List<MenuItem>();
  } 
  public List<MenuItem> Items;
}
```

I think to use `Entity Framework 5` and `Code First` workflow so those classes may be usefull for the future but now it's all dummy data that I create in my controller - using the `HomeController` from the default MVC 4 project created from `Visual Studio 2012` for simplicity. And then render the data in a partial view `_Menu` :

```
@model DynamicMenu.Models.Menu
<ul id="menu">
    @foreach (var item in Model.Items)
    {
        <li><a href="@item.MenuItemPath">@item.MenuItemName</a>
            @if (item.ChildMenuItems.Any())
            {
                <ul>
                    @foreach (var subitem in item.ChildMenuItems)
                    {
                        <li><a href="@subitem.MenuItemPath">@subitem.MenuItemName</a></li>
                    }
                </ul>
            }
        </li>
    }
</ul>
```

Also in my `_Layout` view I have :

```
 @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
 //Next two rows are added
 <link href="../../Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.core.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
 <link href="../../Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.menu.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
 @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
 //some more default code...
 <script>
   $(document).ready(function () {
     $("#menu").menu();
 });
 </script>
```

This example is using `jQuery Menu widget` and seems like it can offer what I need but the problem I want to resolve now is that with the code like this I get the following output :

[image: Menu]

And what I want is to show/hide submenus on mouse hover. With pure `HTML` and `JavaScript/jQuery` i think it would be easier(not sure about that though) but I want(if possible) to stick to the `Razor` view engine.

So my questions are :

- Given the code how can I show hide the submenus on mouse hover?
- Many sites have such kind of menus so I think that maybe there's a standard way to implement such a functionality. Even though my search led only to some partial solutions could someone point me to a site/tutorial where implementing such a functionality is shown/explained?

Comment: I recommend learning a good Javascript data-binding framework (Knockout is my favorite, other popular options are Angular and Backbone) and learning how to use it alongside jQuery to build components like these...that said, you can accomplish your task with mostly CSS and some basic Javascript or jQuery...and I recommend all this over using Razor since these other languages & technologies are more transferable to any project.

Comment: Well, I may end up with some pure JS/CSS implementation but since the task looks trivial to me in the sense that a lot of sites use such type of menu I hope that someone will share a solution, rather than writing my own.

Comment: @Leron I am working on a similar development for my domain website.  I am using Foundation for my implementation.  I am also using EF Fluent API for the data driven part.  As soon as I get the solution implemented ill give you an answer.

Comment: Ty @GoldBishop looking forward to that.

Comment: Having issues but using this url as a guide to implementation: http://rjdudley.com/blog/2013/01/28/creating-a-simple-dynamic-menu-in-asp-net-mvc/